# Rails "script/plugin" install http://github.com...git hangs on 'git pull'

Tags: git, github, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Whenever I run the **rails** script/plugin install to install a plugin using git, from github it "hangs".

```
$ script/plugin -v install http://github.com/ryanstout/blog_kit.git
```

It "hangs". the -v gives me the following output:

```
Plugins will be installed using http
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/XXX/vendor/plugins/blog_kit/.git/
git pull --depth 1 http://github.com/ryanstout/blog_kit.git
```

and that is where it hangs. ('XXX' is edited by me in this outout)

When I break off that command, with *^C*, and run 'git pull --depth 1 ...  by hand, it hangs too.

1. I can clone that repository just fine: network seems not the problem.
2. git is in my path.
3. when running rails -g foo, I get a lot of errors about the directory not being under git. Probably related.
4. 'lsof -i | grep github' shows the following:

   git-remot 11710  ber    8u  IPv4 182786      0t0  TCP yasmine.fritz.box:42324->github.com:www (CLOSE_WAIT)
   git-remot 11710  ber    9u  IPv4 182798      0t0  TCP yasmine.fritz.box:42325->github.com:www (CLOSE_WAIT) 
   git       11712  ber    8u  IPv4 182786      0t0  TCP yasmine.fritz.box:42324->github.com:www (CLOSE_WAIT)

   so it appears there actually is a connection, but nothing gets pulled in.

Any ideas what I can do to dive deeper into this issue? Did I miss some README?

Comment: Have you tried using a different protocol for the remote? Your examples show HTTP, but GitHub.com also supports the Git and SSH protocols.

Comment: how would I do that with ./script/install? I cannot find the options for that.

Comment: Your hint helped me, the command should have been git://...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [ewall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147320/ewall), I found the answer.

Instead of:

script/plugin -v install **http**://github.com/ryanstout/blog_kit.git

use

script/plugin -v install **git**://github.com/ryanstout/blog_kit.git

Comment: Thanks. That also helped me, as authors suggested command "rails plugin install git@github.com:napcs/lazy_developer.git", and it did not work, and I used "rails plugin install git://github.com/napcs/lazy_developer.git" instead, and it worked